# Reportes, informes Tkinter Python

Tags: python, tkinter, informes

Estoy escribiendo un programa simple en Python que solo controla unas deudas y los pagos respectivos. La información se está guardando en una base de datos Mysql. He trabajado la parte gráfica con Tkinter. Mi problema ahora radica en que necesito generar unos reportes o informes de saldos, pagos, etc., y no encuentro un "reporteador" con información clara sobre como hacerlos desde tkinter.  Alguien que tenga experiencia con reportes en Python podría recomendarme alguno y donde encontrar ejemplos de ello? Muchas gracias.

Comment: Hola! Bienvenidx a SOes. 
Las preguntas del tipo "Tengo que hacer esto" sin mostrar el código que has escrito no suelen ser bien recibidas, ya que la respuesta será siempre adivinando y no encaja en el formato del sitio.
Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes.

Comment: Recuerda que puedes [edit] tu pregunta cuantas veces sea necesario (incluso si termina cerrada) y añadir la info relevante a forma de [Ejemplo mínimo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (en los comentarios no se ve bien el código y abajo sólo van nuestros intentos de respuesta). Una buena pregunta siempre termina reabierta :)

Comment: Las preguntas que piden recomendaciones de recursos externos suelen terminar cerradas. Ya que atraen respuestas basadas en opiniones, las cuales no encajan con el formato del sitio.